# Optimised PHP code for multiple input check

Tags: php

There is a PHP update form where a user can update his records. The below-mentioned code looks redundant to me. How can I optimize this PHP code? Also, I have the admins username and email in a different table and the admin detail columns (such as first name, last name, gender, dob) in a different table. What will be the best way to check if username and email both have been updated or if any one of them and update it in the database accordingly.

Below is my source code:

```
   if(isset($_POST['btnClick']) {
    $f_name = NULL;
    $l_name = NULL;
    $username = NULL;
    $email = NULL;
    $gender = NULL;
    $dob = NULL;

    $f_name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "f_name", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $l_name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "l_name", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "username", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "email", FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    $gender = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "gender", FILTER_VALIDATE_STRING);
    $dob = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "dob", FILTER_VALIDATE_STRING);

    try {

        if(isset($username) && $username != $_SESSION['username']) {
            $sqlUpdate = "UPDATE admins SET username=:username WHERE admin_id=:admin_id";
            /*Update code here...*/
            echo "Username changed value inputted";
        }  
        else if(isset($email) && $email != $_SESSION['email']) {
            $sqlUpdate = "UPDATE admins SET username=:username WHERE admin_id=:admin_id";
            /*Update code here...*/
            echo "email change value inputted";
        } 
        else if(isset($username) && isset($email)) {
            /*Update both records */
        }
```

Comment: @Martijn Please avoid redirecting questions to codereview that are likely to be closed there. This one is off-topic for containing hypothetical/stub code.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger It's not a hypothetical code. I just want to improvise the code and want to know the optimization techniques here.

Comment: @Paradox `/*Update code here...*/` is hypothetical and will have poor reception on CR.

Comment: Okay! There are more codes there. Just to make the code short I commented that section.

Comment: [Cross-posted on Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/198132/52915)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<?php
try {
    if (isset($username) && $username != $_SESSION['username']) {
        $fieldsToUpdate[] = 'username=:username';
        $updatedFields[] = 'Username';
    }

    if (isset($email) && $email != $_SESSION['email']) {
        $fieldsToUpdate[] = 'email=:email';
        $updatedFields[] = 'Email';
    }

    if (isset($fieldsToUpdate) && count($fieldsToUpdate) > 0) {
        $sqlUpdate = "UPDATE admins SET " . implode($fieldsToUpdate, ', ') . " WHERE admin_id=:admin_id";
        /*Update code here...*/
        $finalMessage = 'Fields: ' . implode($updatedFields, ', ') . ' have been updated.';
    }
}
```

PS: This is an example code that how can you optimize your code with PHP arrays and implode() function to run single query to update single or multiple fields.